# How do I redirect traffic only if being accessed from a specific port?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, dns

My website, **https://coolkids.gq**, has a Minecraft server hosted on it as well as a web server. It hosts both Bedrock and Java versions of Minecraft (unrelated) and I’ve figured out how to do the Java side but I’m still stuck on the bedrock side as it doesn’t allow SRV records.

I want to be able to access both the webpage and the Minecraft server at `https://coolkids.gq`. The Minecraft server uses port 19132 and the website uses ports 80 and 443 obviously.

When I go to HTTP or HTTPS ports it should take me to the main website, but when I use 19132 it will redirect me to another link that hosts the server, e.g. `myamazingserver.net`. It would be preferred if it redirected to `myamazingserver.net:19132` but just `myamazingserver.net` should work as well.

How, by using .htaccess, HTML, PHP or DNS could I achieve this?

Edit: Bedrock Edition does not support SRV.

Comment: `SRV` records are the solution for that, but 1) DNS servers has to allow it (or more specifically the UI, because otherwise `SRV` records are nothing new or special, any nameserver handles them) and 2) client applications need to query for them and use them... and web browsers unfortunately specifically DO NOT use `SRV` records (do not query for them, do not take them into account). Hence you will need to use a reverse proxy setup to do things like you want.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I believe that Minecraft clients do support SRV records.  So it should be possible to run the web server on the default ports and the Minecraft server on some other port.   I'm not sure about sharing the URL though.  Minecraft should use its own protocol.  It shouldn't use HTTPS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That is my understanding too. https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/how-to-set-an-srv-record-for-your-minecraft-server/

Comment: Java Edition does, but Bedrock edition does not and I am having issues with Bedrock edition...

Answer (score 2):

Although Patrick is correct in saying that web browsers do not support `SRV` records, Minecraft **does** support them, so there's no need for a reverse proxy setup.

According to [this NameCheap tutorial](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9765/2208/how-can-i-link-my-domain-name-to-a-minecraft-server), you'll need to create an `SRV` record with the following info:

> Service: _minecraft
>
> Protocol: _tcp
>
> Priority: 0
>
> Weight: 5
>
> Port: [custom port]
>
> Target: [your domain]

The record needed for other domain registrars should be very similar.

After this is set up, you'll still be able to access your website at `https://coolkids.gq`, but you'll also be able to access your Minecraft server at `coolkids.gq` (note the lack of `https://` since Minecraft afaik has no URI scheme).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  They want to redirect the Minecraft connections to another server.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Unless I'm grossly mistaken, this does redirect the Minecraft connections to another server, though. The server that it redirects to is whatever you put in the `Target` section of the SRV record, and the destination port of the redirect is what you put in the `Port` section.

Comment: Bedrock edition does not support SRV records.

Comment: Oh. I forgot there was a "new" version of Minecraft. I only ever worked with the original "Java Edition" servers. Good luck.

Comment: The server is compatible with both bedrock and java - some software converts the Java commands to C++ for bedrock users. I think I’m going to use a Reverse proxy.